# How to find Steering Angle Sensor (SAS) over the CAN Bus of an Chrysler Volt / Opel Ampera

Tags: reverse-engineering, can-bus, obd-ii, bus

Today I've managed to get a connection from a Opel Ampera to my Notebook over CAN. I used a "Tiny CAN II XL" with the software "busmaster".

There exist many list of CAN ID's for several cars. Sadly I haven't found the ID of the Steering Angle Sensor for an Opel Ampera. A Chrysler Volt should have the same ID's, but didn't found its ID either.

Does one of you know, on which ID I could take a look?

Reverse engineering of the CAN bus would be another way I guess. 
Busmaster didn't allow me much filtering. I think there aren't many more programms which work with the "Tiny CAN II XL". Just looking on the raw data by eye didn't worked so far...
Any ideas how I could find the changing value and deducing the SAS with this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Youtuber DanH142, who's been using a Chrysler Volt to play Mario Cart, the Steering Wheel Angle is on 0x1E5

I've tested that with the Opel Ampera. Seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge list for VAG cars, but I've found it to be similar offset with other car manufacturers.

For example 7E0 is the engine computer so it would be this value + 0x7DF

```
ECU = 0x01
AUTO_TRANS = 0x02
ABS = 0x03
STEERING_ANGLE = 0x04
ACC_START_AUTHORIZATION = 0x05
SEAT_MEMORY_PASS = 0x06
CONTROL_HEAD = 0x07
AUTO_HVAC = 0x08
CENTRAL_ELECTRONICS = 0x09
SECONDARY_AIR_HEATING = 0x0B
DOOR_SLIDE_LEFT = 0x0D
MEDIA_PLAYER_1 = 0x0E
DIGITAL_RAIDO = 0x0F
PARK_ASSIST = 0x10
ECU_II = 0x11
CLUTCH = 0x12
AUTO_DIST_REG = 0x13
SUSPENSION_ELECTRONICS = 0x14
AIRBAG = 0x15
STEERING_WHEEL = 0x16
INSTRUMENTS = 0x17
AUX_HEAT = 0x18
CAN_GATEWAY = 0x19
ACTIVE_STEERING = 0x1B
POSITION_SENSING = 0x1C
DRIVER_IDENTIFICATION = 0x1D
MEDIA_PLAYER_2 = 0x1E
SAT_TUNER = 0x1F
ECU_III = 0x21
AWD = 0x22
BRAKE_BOOSTER = 0x23
ANTI_SLIP = 0x24
IMMOBILIZER = 0x25
AUTO_ROOF = 0x26
CONTROL_HEAD_REAR = 0x27
HVAC_REAR = 0x28
LEFT_LIGHT = 0x29
INTERCOM = 0x2D
MEDIA_PLAYER_3 = 0x2E
DIGITAL_TV = 0x2F
ENGINE_OTHER = 0x31
DIFFERENTIAL_LOCKS = 0x32
LEVEL_CONTROL = 0x34
CENTRAL_LOCKS = 0x35
SEAT_MEMORY_DRIVER = 0x36
NAVIGATION = 0x37
ROOF_ELECTRONICS = 0x38
RIGHT_LIGHT = 0x39
LANE_CHANGE = 0x3C
SPECIAL_FUNCTION = 0x3D
MEDIA_PLAYER_4 = 0x3E
DIESEL_PUMP = 0x41
DOOR_ELECTRONICS_DRIVER = 0x42
BRAKE_ASSIST = 0x43
STEERING_ASSIST = 0x44
INTERNAL_MONITOR = 0x45
CENTRAL_CONV = 0x46
SOUND_SYSTEM = 0x47
SEAT_REAR_DRIVER = 0x48
AUTOMATIC_LIGHT = 0x49
TIRE_PRESSURE_II = 0x4C
DATA_TRANSFER = 0x4D
CONTROL_HEAD_RIGHT_REAR = 0x4E
CENTRAL_ELECTRONICS_II = 0x4F
ELECTRIC_DRIVE = 0x51
DOOR_ELECTRONICS_PASS = 0x52
PARKING_BRAKE = 0x53
REAR_SPOILER = 0x54
HEADLIGHT_RANGE = 0x55
RADIO = 0x56
TV_TUNER = 0x57
AUX_FUEL_TANK = 0x58
TOW_PROTECTION = 0x59
LANE_MAINTAIN = 0x5C
OPERATIONS = 0x5D
CONTROL_HEAD_LEFT_REAR = 0x5E
INFROMATION_ELECTRONICS = 0x5F
BATTERY_REGULATOR = 0x61
DOOR_ELECTRONICS_REAR_LEFT = 0x62
ENTRY_ASSIST_DRIVER = 0x63
STABILIZERS = 0x64
TIRE_PRESSURE = 0x65
SEAT_REAR = 0x66
VOICE_CONTROL = 0x67
WIPER_ELECTRONICS = 0x68
TRAILER = 0x69
BACKUP_CAMERA = 0x6C
TRUNK_ELECTRONICS = 0x6D
CONTROL_HEAD_ROOF = 0x6E
CENTRAL_CONV_II = 0x6F
BATTERY_CHARGER = 0x71
DOOR_ELECTRONICS_REAR_RIGHT = 0x72
ENTRY_ASSIST_PASS = 0x73
CHASSIS_CONTROL = 0x74
TELEMATICS = 0x75
PARK_ASSIST_II = 0x76
TELEPHONE = 0x77
DOOR_SLIDE_RIGHT = 0x78
AUX_HEAT_II = 0x7D
CONTROL_HEAD_DASH = 0x7E
INFORMATION_ELECTRONICS_II = 0x7F
LT3_ENGINE = 0x91
LT3_TRANSMISSION_ = 0x92
LT3_IMMO = 0x93
LT3_AIRBAG = 0x94
LT3_ESP = 0x95
LT3_INSTRUMENTS = 0x96
LT3_TRIP_RECORDER = 0x97
LT3_TIRE_PRESSURE = 0x98
LT3_IGN_SWITCH = 0x99
LT3_CENTRAL_LOCKS = 0x9A
LT3_DRIVER_DOOR = 0x9B
LT3_HVAC = 0x9C
LT3_AUX_HEAT_FUEL = 0x9D
LT3_AUX_HEAD_ELEC = 0x9E
LT3_STAT_HEAT_WATER = 0x9F
LT3_RADIO = 0xA0
LT3_NAVIGATION = 0xA1
LT3_CD_CHANGER = 0xA2
LT3_TELEPHONE = 0xA3
LT3_ROOF_DISPLAY = 0xB0
LT3_UPPER_CONSOLE = 0xB1
LT3_PARK_ASSIST = 0xB2
LT3_TRAILER_MODULE = 0xB3
LT3_CENTRAL_ELECTRONICS = 0xB4
LT3_SPECIAL_FUNCTION = 0xB5
LT3_STEERING_WHEEL = 0xB6
LT3_BATTERY_MANAGEMENT = 0xC1
LT3_SLIDE_DOOR_LEFT = 0xD2
LT3_SLIDE_DOOR_RIGHT = 0xD3
```

Comment: wow awesome! thank you, ill test it out. by the way, thank you for the offset tipp. could get quite useful.

Comment: Haven't found the SAS yet. Is there some kind of request which needs to be send first or some kind of enable-signal?

Comment: Sorry for not replying I see you found it.  The best way to find stuff like this in the future would be to use a CAN logger in the car and then turn the steering wheel and see what changes.

Comment: no problem. you already helped a lot. thats what i did. had just no luck whilst observating. not sure if i did oversee the id or if i might haven‘t displayed all values. however, thanks!